# Interfering type parameter based on another type parameter

Tags: kotlin, generics, types

Is it possible to Kotlin Compiler to infer type parameter based on another type parameter?
That is: infere type A based on type B in `IntExample` class definition.

```kotlin
interface Something<A>

interface Example<A, B: Something<A>>

class IntSomething: Something<Int>

// Can Int type parameter be infered by the fact that IntSomething is Something<Int>?
// If yes, how could I specify B type parameter without specifing the infered A (Int) parameter?
class IntExample: Example<Int, IntSomething> // specifing Int here is painful!!!
```

Imagine that we have more type parameters like that - it will be a lot of boilerplate to specify each of them if some might (theoretically) be infered.

**EDIT**

After an exhausive respose from @KarstenGabriel I will extend the previous example, to make it clear what for are the type parameters used here:

```kotlin
interface Something<A> {
   val sth: A
}

interface Example<A, B: Something<A>> {
   val eg: A
   val something: B  
}

data class IntSomething(override val sth: Int): Something<Int>

data class DescribedIntSomething(
    override val sth: Int, 
    val description: String
): Something<Int>

data class DescribedIntExample(
   override val eg: Int,
   override val something: DescribedIntSomething,
): Example<Int, DescribedIntSomething> // specifing Int here is painful

fun main() {
  val describedIntExample = DescribedIntExample(
    eg = 1,
    something = DescribedIntSomething(1, "Just one")
  )
  
  // We have to know that something is DescribedIntSomething to read description.
  // Neither `*` nor `Something<Int>` is sufficient, we need `B: Something<Int>` to keep B
  val description = describedIntExample.something.description 
  println(description)
}
```

So we use the type parameters - `A` and `B` as `return` values from `eg` and `something`

1. Wildcard `*` cannot be used as it is just means `Any?`. We need to keep concrete type `B`. (eg. to enable reading descrption in the example)
2. Wildcard `Something<Int>` cannot be used instead of `B: Something<Int>` for thesame reason as in the point 1

Maybe it's just an language design level. The type parameters do exists in compile time (they are ereased later), so *theoretically* `Example<DescribedIntSomething>` might be sufficient instead of `Example<Int, DescribedIntSomething>` as `DescribedIntSomething` is `Something<Int>`

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but as a reader of the code, I'd think having to specity Int makes it easier to read.

Comment: As I understand the language syntax, type inference is an all-or-nothing thing: there's no way to supply only _some_ type parameters, and have it infer the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solvable under some assumptions:

1. You need type parameter `A` only for property `eg` (or other similar cases).
2. It is okay that we convert `eg` to be a function instead of a property.
3. The desired value for `eg` (your `A` value) can be derived from the value of `something` (your `B` value). If the value is not inferred, then it is not possible to infer the type.

We then define `Example` without parameter `A`:

```
interface Example<B: Something<*>> {
    val something: B
}
```

Now inside `Example` we do not have a possibility to obtain the type parameter of `B`'s `Something`-type, because the type parameter `A` on `Something<A>` does not exist at runtime. So you cannot just ask an instance of `B` what its `Something`-type parameter is. And Kotlin cannot do that either, because the information is just not there, if it is not explicitly specified by you.

But we know the parameter at compile-time which can be used in an inline extension function with reified parameter:

```
inline fun <reified A, reified B : Something<A>> Example<B>.eg(): A = something.sth
```

(documentation: [Inline functions with reified parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) and [Extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters))

In this example I assume that `eg` should have the value of `sth`.

If you want `eg` to be private, you can put the function inside `Example` and make it private, otherwise it must be specified outside of the class.

Now you can just define your subclass without the need to specify the former `A` parameter, but you still have the right type:

```
data class DescribedIntExample(
    override val something: DescribedIntSomething,
) : Example<DescribedIntSomething>

fun main() {
    val describedIntExample = DescribedIntExample(
        something = DescribedIntSomething(1, "Just one")
    )
    val x = describedIntExample.eg() // x has inferred type Int and value 1
}
```

Comment: I addressed your question im my edited post

Comment: @PGliw I read your edited post, but unfortunately I think there (currently) is no way in Kotlin to express this. You definitely need the parameter `A` to express that `B` should not be of type `Something<Any?>` . I agree with you that it is probably only a restriction of the language. If there was something like _inline interfaces_ with reified type parameters, then it would not be necessary to define `A` for each subtype, because it could then be derived from `B`, but Kotlin does not offer something like that.

Comment: thanks to your response. That's excatly what I wanted to confirm. Please update your answer with the content of your last comment so that I can accept it :)

Comment: @PGliw I rewrote my answer because I think that I found a solution that's hopefully more helpful than what I wrote before.

Comment: that's a very clever solution, thanks! We could use extension propterty insread of function to keep our previous syntax: `inline val <reified A, reified B : Something<A>> Example<B>.eg: A get() = something.sth`